# Hamiltonian graphs of integers $n$

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

For which integers of $n$ is $K_{4,n}$ Hamiltonian?
I know it is a complete bipartite graph, and there are $4$ vertices on one end and $n$ in the other. My guess is that $n$ would be the set: $\{4,5,6,\dotsc,n\}$ so that it can only occur once.

Answer (score 2):

Any Hamiltonian cycle must have length $n+4$ with every other vertex being in the first part. Can you figure it out from that?